# get "what are you up to?" text from Venue Push API

Tags: foursquare

I'm using venue push api with venue i'm managing and it works as intended.
But we want to organize some sort of poll using "what are you up to?" text, is there a way to get this text in push api?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [real-time API docs](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime), the text you're looking for (Foursquare calls them "shouts") is omitted from the Venue Push API for privacy reasons.